# RxJs chain two http calls - ASP.NET Core MVC Web Api

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, rxjs

I try to chain two http requests (to a ASP.NET Core MVC Web Api). Order is important so i tried to use `.flatMap()`.

1. I want to create a user
2. I want to call get user method (which is on a separate microservice)

   ```
   constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

   getUser(): Observable<User | null> {
       if (!this.retrieve("IsAuthorized") || (this.retrieve("Email") === "" || this.retrieve("Email") === null)) {
           return Observable.of(null);
       }

       return this.getUserByEmail(this.retrieve("Email"))
           .do((user: User) => {
               this.setCurrentUser(user);
           });
   }

   public createUser(email: string, familyName: string, givenName: string, phoneNumber: string, gender: string): Observable<User | null> {
       let createUser = this.dataService.post(this.usersApiUrl, null, {
           Email: email, FamilyName: familyName,
           GivenName: givenName, PhoneNumber: phoneNumber, Gender: gender
       }).map(response => response.json());

       return createUser.flatMap((res: Response) => { return this.getUser(); })
   }

   private setCurrentUser(user: User) {
       this.currentUser.next(user);
   }

   private getUserByEmail(email: string): Observable<User> {
       return this.dataService.get(this.usersApiUrl, email).map(response => response.json());
   }
   ```

`this.currentUser` is a `ReplaySubject<User> = new ReplaySubject<User>(1);`

Current behavior: POST (create user) works as expected. GET (`this.getUser()`) doesn't get called.

P.S: I'm not really interested in create user response because that will only tell me that it succeeded.

Update:

```
private retrieve(key: string): any {
        var item = this.storage.getItem(key);

        if (item && item !== 'undefined') {
            return JSON.parse(this.storage.getItem(key));
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Where `this.storage` is `localStorage`.

And i subscribe to this in a classic manner:

```
this.userService.createUser(this.authService.email, this.authService.familyName,
    this.authService.givenName, this.authService.phoneNumber, this.authService.gender).subscribe(() => { });
```

Comment: but what is not working? Probably you would want to post all of your code (including `this.retreive()`,`this.currentUser` and the place you use `.flatMap()`, so that it's easier to debug

Comment: @CozyAzure I updated my question with subscribe call and retrieve function. As i said, currently it just fires the create user http call, but it never gets to get user afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial attempt was correct from a Rx & client-side point of view.

The problem is related to ASP.NET Core MVC web API where:

```
[HttpPost] 
public void Post([FromBody]CreateUserRequest request)
{ 
  _userService.Create(request); 
}
```

Returns a 200 with empty content instead of 204 (No Content) and that cause stream (rx) failure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api

You can change that to:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Post([FromBody]CreateUserRequest request)
 {
   _userService.Create(request);
   return NoContent();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you do is invoke `createUser` method, than I think `getUser` is not firing since nothing is subscribing to it. Add `.subscribe()` to `getUser` invocation and see if this helps.

Comment: That will mean to modify my return type and i'm not really looking into that. Basically i want to keep returning a Observable<User> and inside that function i'd like to have a chain of http calls - create + get and to be able to subscribe to this one.

Comment: If you want to keep the return type, don't return straight away, use temporary variable such as `let obs = this.getUserByEmail...`, then `obs.subscribe()` and `return obs;`

Comment: I've tried this approach and it has the same behavior.